# get angular-strap to coexist with bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to replace bootstrap-datepicker and bootstrap-timepicker in my app with angular-strap datepicker and timepicker directives and i'm facing some trouble:

I have one view where I still depend on bootstrap-datepicker (I need the inline datepicker), and when I load the bootstrap-datepicker css it breaks my angular-strap datepicker.

[image: angular-strap datepicker]

I guess they are using the same CSS classes, but how could I let the two of them coexist (without having to hack in the code of neither of them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular-strap's components don't require extra css, but they could be broken by some extra styles from `bootstrap-datepicker` because they also have `datepicker` class on yourself.

So you have 2 options:

1. Do not use both datepickers on the same page. I don't mean whole app, just include styles only on that pages, where it is really needed.
2. Override angular-strap templates and remove this class name. Add the following into your angular code

Code:

```
angular.module('app', []).config(function($datepickerProvider) {
  // path for your overriden template       
  $datepickerProvider.template = 'templates/custom-datepicker.tpl.html'; 
});
```

Then copy template from [angular-strap sources](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.tpl.html), remove `datepicker` class from first line and save it by path as described in config above. Now it will be used instead of default.

It is only temporary solution, to help you keep work while migration is going. This libraries do exactly the same thins, so conflicts is quite possible.

Comment: I went for option 2, I think its the most clean one. The downside is that I have to remember this changes each time I update angular-strap.